# Putting cookies in a list in python

Tags: python, cookies, tornado

I've created a list of letters in python to print out just for pseudocode, I'm actually trying to print out a list of users(cookies) from my webserver (Tornado Python). Here is my current code:

```
 clients = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'xx', 'zzz'] # Cookies should be put here in this list
    print clients[0]
```

I've considered placing one of the following inside the list:

```
 self.login = self._get_current_user(callback=self.on_auth)
 self.login = self.get_secure_cookie('user', str(datadecoded['user']))
 self.login = self.get_secure_cookie("user")
```

However I'm not sure how it would work out as in the end it would just be:

```
 clients = ['self.login']
```

And that appears to be quite flawed, so is there a way I can store my users cookies inside a list and be able to randomly call on them to print as seen in the pseudocode?

Comment: It's very unclear what your problem is. If you want to put a variable into a list, you need to use the bare name, not a string of the name. If you want to place multiple values in, you need to use different names, or put them directly into the literal: `[self._get_current_user(callback=self.on_auth), self.get_secure_cookie('user', str(datadecoded['user'])), self.get_secure_cookie("user")]`.

Comment: I'm trying to put all the users that are online inside the clients list. Since I have no way of determining how many users will be online, I can't just put [self.login, self.login, etc.] inside the list. When a user logs in, their cookie will be added to the list automatically

Comment: So you want to set it to an empty list (`clients = []`), each time they log in, you add to that list (`clients.append(self.get_secure_cookie("user"))`). Setting `self.login` multiple times doesn't make a list, it just overrides the old value.

Comment: I'd like to know how to set the clients = [] to an empty list and each time a user logs in they are added into the list. And be able to print the first client's user.

Comment: Or you can convert this `client` list into a comma-separated str,then set this str into cookies